# Single Table Inheritance and Yaml configuration

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, yaml

I want to use in my project Single Table Inheritance for symfony2/doctrine, but I can't find any working examples with yaml configuration for it. In official documentation there is only annotation configuration presented. I found xml examples, but I want to use yaml configuration. Can somebody help and share with some working code?

Answer (score 12):

Okay built-in converter saves life.

In order to save time this an example of inheritance converted into yaml :

```
#file: Resources/config/doctrine/Person.orm.yml
Person:
  type: entity
  table: null
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE
  discriminatorColumn:
    name: discr
    type: string
    length: 255
  discriminatorMap:
    person: Person
    employee: Employee
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }


#file: Resources/config/doctrine/Employee.orm.yml
Employee:
  type: entity
  table: null
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: Note that, with symfony 2.2, classes are not generated by the console's command 'doctrine:generate:entities' unless the classes are manually created.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [an example of YAML markup](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/basic-mapping.html):

Entities config files should be put into `src/Acme/StoreBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/<EntityName>.orm.yml` according to [reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html).

Also built-in converter can be used: [how to model inheritance in doctrine2 with yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265105/how-to-model-inheritance-in-doctrine2-with-yaml)

Comment: Tx, I have read this and I'm using yaml markup in my application right now, but I have problem with [Inheritance Mapping](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html). I need example for [7.2 Single table inheritance](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) in yaml markup.

Comment: @Krzysztof Lenda: You can use converter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265105/how-to-model-inheritance-in-doctrine2-with-yaml

Comment: Thank you. This converter seems to be very useful tool - I didn't know it earlier. I think, I can handle it now!