# How to do inheritance using yaml in Doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, yaml, fosuserbundle

Im trying to use FOS UserBundle And I need to create an user entiy with extending BaseUser from the FOSUserBundle.

Here is my User.orm.yml

```
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE
discriminatorColumn:
  name: discr
  type: string
  length: 255
discriminatorMap:
  user: User
  baseUser: BaseUser
```

I didnt forget to extends BaseUser but I just dont know how to do that.
The [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) only show how to do that using annotation.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is example of [SINGLE_TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978921/single-table-inheritance-and-yaml-configuration) inheritance.
This is also some useful [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265105/how-to-model-inheritance-in-doctrine2-with-yaml).
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I try it (updated on my post) but It can not find the entity class BaseUser (It should be in the FOSUserBundle)

Comment: @fliim here is the part of code from FOSUserBundle Documentation: `use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;`

Comment: This only shows that FOSUserBundle has no `BaseUser` becaues it has `User`

Comment: I dont understand what you means.Do you have an example of a working yaml ?

Comment: @fliim If i right you need make inheritance inside [entity class](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#a-doctrine-orm-user-class) (not yaml).

Comment: yes I only found this way to do what I wanted too. Thanks for your help